# How to include many archives in only one archive

Tags: include

firstly, I apologize if I wrote something wrong or in an inappropriately way, but this is my first post here and I didn't find a tutorial about how use this forum. Now, let's go to the problem: I'm trying include many archives in only one archive, but I can include until the archive "2014.02". The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{empheq,amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\begin{document}

{\huge \textbf{Test}}
\include{1995.02/1995.02}
\include{1996.01/1996.01}
\include{1996.02/1996.02}
\include{1997.01/1997.01}
\include{1997.02/1997.02}
\include{1998.01/1998.01}
\include{1998.02/1998.02}
\include{1999.01/1999.01}
\include{1999.02/1999.02}
\include{2000.01/2000.01}
\include{2000.02/2000.02}
\include{2001.01/2001.01}
\include{2001.02/2001.02}
\include{2002.01/2002.01}
\include{2002.02/2002.02}
\include{2003.01/2003.01}
\include{2003.02/2003.02}
\include{2004.01/2004.01}
\include{2004.02/2004.02}
\include{2005.01/2005.01}
\include{2005.02/2005.02}
\include{2006.01/2006.01}
\include{2006.02/2006.02}
\include{2007.01/2007.01}
\include{2007.02/2007.02}
\include{2008.01/2008.01}
\include{2008.02/2008.02}
\include{2009.01/2009.01}
\include{2009.02/2009.02}
\include{2010.01/2010.01}
\include{2010.02/2010.02}
\include{2011.01/2011.01}
\include{2011.02/2011.02}
\include{2012.01/2012.01}
\include{2012.02/2012.02}
\include{2013.01/2013.01}
\include{2013.02/2013.02}
\include{2014.01/2014.01}
\include{2014.02/2014.02}
\include{2015.01/2015.01}
\include{2015.02/2015.02}
\include{2016.01/2016.01}
\include{2016.02/2016.02}
\include{2017.01/2017.01}
\include{Observations/Observations}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I found my mistake: I added "\end{document}" in the final of archive "2014.02.tex". That's the reason that the PDF generated didn't show the archives "2015.01.tex" until "Observations".

Thanks a lot by the people who try to help me!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't quite get what you are trying to achieve. To only include some of them?

Comment: I'm trying include in only one archive  all this archives: "1995.02" until "2017.01" and "Observations", but I can include only "1995.02" until "2014.02"

Comment: Why? Which error appears?

Comment: The tutorial about how to use this site is this: [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: By “archive” you mean a LaTeX source file, don’t you?  For example, when you say `\include{2017.01/2017.01}`, you want to include a file named `2017.01.tex`, which is found in a directory named `2017.01/` which, in turn, is located inside the same directory as your main source file, right?

Comment: @GuM, yes that's it.

Comment: that is what the code that you post does, so if you do not get that there is something that you have not shown. Also you almost certainly do not want `\everymath{\displaystyle}` (which will give very poor math typesetting in general.

Comment: the later tex files will be included unless the file is missing, or you have `\includeonly` command specifying that only some files should be included. The log file should show the reason for the files not being included.

Comment: @TeXnician, the generated PDF show only until the archive "2014.01.tex"

Comment: That does not really help. Could you please show us your log file?

Comment: @TeXnician, I edited my post, I couldn't put all the log file, but I put the end of log file, where I believe that show what it's the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP just inserted `\end{document}` in his document.